# What is the keyboard shortcut for method suggestions in AndroidStudio on Mac OS X?

Tags: android, methods, shortcut

i don't find it in preferences/keymap.

I want to set cmd+space for method suggestions.

In eclipse i find it under "content assist", but in android studio?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Windows, it is there. On Mac, should be there too.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yes. In Mac, it's in Android Studio Preferences -> Keymap -> Main Menu -> Code -> Code Completion -> Basic.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborated from the accepted answer from user1214609, here is how to get it done in Android Studio in Mac.

Preferences -> Keymap -> Main Menu -> Code -> Code Completion -> Basic

[image]